# Android Activity with Listview keeps throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to create a ListView that displays 2 TextViews per row.

However I keep getting a NullPointerException when opening the Activity and I have no idea why (logCat logs don't tell me which line(s) on my end create the problem).

Here's the relevant code:

**The main class EventViewActivity**

```
public class EventViewActivity extends ListActivity {
public String[] eventTitles;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eventview_layout);

    eventTitles = new String[]{                 
            getResources().getString(R.string.eventtitle1),
            getResources().getString(R.string.eventtitle2),
            getResources().getString(R.string.eventtitle3),
            getResources().getString(R.string.eventtitle4),
            getResources().getString(R.string.eventtitle5)
    };

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.eventview_layout, R.id.row_title, eventTitles));
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.eventview_layout, R.id.row_descr, eventTitles));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have clicked an item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

layout.xml is:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
       <ListView android:id="@+id/android:eventlist" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/eventview_background"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the logcat and also your `eventview_layout.xml`

Comment: yeah for some reason when i add the eventview_layout and the eventview_row, i can't post the question because not all code is allegedly indented right

Comment: the eventview layout:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 
 <ListView android:id="@+id/android:eventlist"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/eventview_background"/>
    
    
</LinearLayout>

Comment: the eventview_row:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
 <TextView 
     android:id="@+id/row_title"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:padding="10dip" />    
     
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/row_descr"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:padding="10dip"
/>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: can you post your logcat??? that'll help debug.

Comment: the error was using R.layout.eventview_layout insteadof R.layout.eventview_row in my ArrayAdapter.
However, it seems I can use a Listadapter only once? It sets the last ListAdapter, but it doesn't set the first. However when I comment the last, it does set the first.

Answer (score 0):

does your `eventview_layout` has a ListView with id `android:id="@android:id/list"` ..?  if not add it.. i assume its not done

a small correction..

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical" > 
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/eventview_background"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

its necessary that the contentView of ListACtivity has a listView with exact same Id..

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are approaching for ListView is not the correct.

Please have A look on this sample [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom) to have complete view how create a ListView with custom adapter.

The above link has sample application created with listview and each listitem having two text fields as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the:

```
super.onCreate();
```

first!